# Achieve object projection effect with box-shadow

Tags: css, css-shapes, box-shadow

I am trying to achieve this effect in CSS:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
#test {position: relative;margin: 100px;}
#test::after {
  background-color: maroon;
  box-shadow: 0 -50px 10px 7px gray;
  height: 45px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom 0;
  width: 60px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

but I am not achieving the expected result with the cast shadow. I wonder if its even possible to do this with CSS only?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/1/)

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle?

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/1/

Comment: You can sort of achieve this multiple pseudo elements like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/2/). Don't think this is possible with shadow alone. You could add a blur filter (at present, webkit only) to make the gray area look more like a shadow.

Comment: That looks about right. However im already using pseudoelement ::before for a different effect. Is it possible to use an additional pseudoelement?

Comment: What about :first-line?

Comment: Nevermind, I just read it cant be used in this case.

Comment: @CainNuke: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/6/) is the closest I could create without using any extra real/pseudo-elements. It uses gradients on the parent to produce the effect. If that solves your problem, I will post as answer.

Comment: Yes, it does. Excellent solution, thank you.

Comment: No problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I added another element representing the shadow:

```
#shadow {
  height: 90px;
  left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 60px;
  transform: perspective(50px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -106px 20px 17px #808080;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/4/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that would require to change the html. I think using pseudo-elements will be a better approach but I already used up ::before and ::after

Comment: You can actually remove both divs and use only `before` and `after` if you wish https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/5/

Comment: I mean I already used up ::before for a different effect not shown in my question. Otherwise I would use your solution because thats exactly the effect I want. If only was possible to have an additional pseudo-element other than ::before and ::after.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496459/achieve-object-projection-effect-with-box-shadow#comment62488605_37496459), I would generally recommend the approach used in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcyy09mp/2/) (which is, use another pseudo-element) or the one in Martin's answer (which is, to use an extra element) but as you've mentioned that the other pseudo-element is already used and you are trying to avoid any extra elements, the other approach is to use gradients as `background` for the parent element. By using the appropriate side-to-side gradients with `background-position`, `background-size`, we can not only get the shape but also an effect very similar to the blurred nature of the shadow.

Below is a sample snippet: (*the output is also reasonably responsive as you can see by hovering it*)

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 45%, gray 55%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 45%, gray 55%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, gray), linear-gradient(gray, gray);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 95%, 30px 95%, calc(100% - 60px) 8px, calc(100% - 60px) calc(100% - 8px);
  background-position: 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 4px, 50% 100%;
}

#test::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center top 0;
}

/* just for demo */

#test {
  transition: all 1s;
}
#test:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

In the below snippet, I have given a different color for each of the gradient just to visually show how it is achieved.

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 45%, red 55%), linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 45%, blue 55%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, green), linear-gradient(rebeccapurple, rebeccapurple);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 95%, 30px 95%, calc(100% - 60px) 8px, calc(100% - 60px) calc(100% - 8px);
  background-position: 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 4px, 50% 100%;
}

#test::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center top 0;
}

/* just for demo */

#test {
  transition: all 1s;
}
#test:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-background-20100612/box-shadow.src.html), "the 'box-shadow' property attaches one or more ***drop-shadows*** to the box". The shadow you want to create is not a [drop shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shadow) so there is no CSS that would make the shadow in the picture.

The closest you could achieve is pushing the shadow off one edge by using a [negative spread radius](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/#article-header-id-4):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#test {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: maroon;
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 7px -6px black;
  height: 45px;
  width: 60px;
  transform: perspective(150px) rotateX(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: There is no way to flip only the shadow vertically to achieve the effect or something?

Comment: @CainNuke No, but perhaps you could achieve the effect with an SVG.